# UI выбор диапазона цены не свайпается на мобайле

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, jquery-ui

Есть [сайт](https://dzpower.000webhostapp.com/ispania/), я подключил UI-ползунок с выбором диапазона, на ПК всё нормально, но на мобайле точки не двигаются под пальцем, а надо чтобы двигались, параметр меняется, если просто нажать на оранжевую полоску, тогда да - точка меняет своё местоположение. Пожалуйста, если кто сталкивался с таким, помогите сделать так, чтобы оно нормально работало и на мобайлах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого плагин jQuery UI Touch Punch.

Подключаете jquery, потом jquery-ui (в нем обязательно два виджета jquery.ui.widget.js и jquery.ui.mouse.js)  и потом подключаете jQuery UI Touch Punch.

Взять можно например отсюда: http://touchpunch.furf.com/